# Adding products to Magento menu

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Today I am trying to add products like this:

```
– Category
– – SubCategory1
– – – Product 1
– – – Product 2
– – – Product 3
– – SubCategory2
– – – Product 1
– – – Product 2
– – – Product 3
```

My current magento version is ver. 1.9.0.1 
I was searching about it on the internet I found this code but its giving me syntax error not sure why. Please check but this code tested on Magento ver 1.4 I am not sure if it will work for me or not.

```
    protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, $isFirst = false,
        $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false)
    {
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            return '';
        }
        $html = array();

        // get all children
        if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {
            $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
            $childrenCount = count($children);
        } else {
            $children = $category->getChildren();
            $childrenCount = $children->count();
        }
        $hasChildren = ($children && $childrenCount);

        // select active children
        $activeChildren = array();
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($child->getIsActive()) {
                $activeChildren[] = $child;
            }
        }
        $activeChildrenCount = count($activeChildren);
        $hasActiveChildren = ($activeChildrenCount > 0);

        // prepare list item html classes
        $classes = array();
        $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
        $classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
        if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
        $linkClass = '';
        if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
            $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
            $linkClass = ' class="'.$outermostItemClass.'"';
        }
        if ($isFirst) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
        }
        if ($isLast) {
            $classes[] = 'last';
        }
        if ($hasActiveChildren) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }

        // prepare list item attributes
        $attributes = array();
        if (count($classes) > 0) {
            $attributes['class'] = implode(' ', $classes);
        }
        if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
             $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
             $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
        }

        // assemble list item with attributes
        $htmlLi = '<li'; foreach="" ($attributes="" as="" $attrname=""> $attrValue) {
            $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
        }
        $htmlLi .= '>';
        $html[] = $htmlLi;

        $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'" '.$linkclass.'="">';
        $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';


        // Grabbing the products for the category if it's level is 1
        if ($level == 1) {

            $catId = $category->getId();
            $categorie = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
            $categorie->load($catId); // this is category id
            $collection = $categorie->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc');
            $html[] = '<ul>';

            foreach ($collection as $pc)
            {
                $p = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
                $p->load($pc->getId());

                $data = $p->_data;
                $html[] = '<li><a href="/'.$data['url_path'].'">'.$data['name'] .'</a></li>'; 
            }

            $html[] = "</ul>\n";


        }
        // Done

        // render children
        $htmlChildren = '';
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {
            $htmlChildren .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $child,
                ($level + 1),
                ($j == $activeChildrenCount - 1),
                ($j == 0),
                false,
                $outermostItemClass,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                $noEventAttributes
            );
            $j++;
        }
        if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
            if ($childrenWrapClass) {
                $html[] = '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
            }
            $html[] = '<ul class="level' . $level . '">';
            $html[] = $htmlChildren;
            $html[] = '</ul>';
            if ($childrenWrapClass) {
                $html[] = '</div>';
            }
        }

        $html[] = '';

        $html = implode("\n", $html);
        return $html;
    }
</li';>
```

Its giving syntax error on line:

```
$htmlLi = '<li'; foreach="" ($attributes="" as="" $attrname=""> $attrValue) {
```

and at the end of code:

```
</li';>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are recieving?

Comment: copy pasting the entire navigation.php file here is not a good idea and most people will refuse to analyze such a large portion of code. I suggest to try and narrow the issue and then edit your question